# Shri Vyaasa-virachitam Navagraha-stotram

Tags: vyasa, stotra, navagraha

Vyasa has composed Navagraha stotram for the nine planets which comprise two lines. Daily recitation of this will bring good. Adverse effects of the planets will not be there as per legends. What are the stotras with meanings?

Comment: It is quite easy to find it from Google. Also found in every Stotra/Kavacha books that are there in market.

Comment: @Rickross For that I cannot go to market and buy. If you know tell the answer. Marking negative votes is not fair. The answers given are copied by citing the sources. But the contents are not known to anybody.

Comment: Regarding downvotes u never know who has and for what reasons. But the fact is it's too easy to answer this one. And if u really want an answer from me then i'm doing it.

Comment: Even I have answer. Whatever the questions I ask answer is there for that with me. That is why people prefer quora.

Comment: If u know the answer then u can self answer. But normally people ask questions of which they don't the answers.

Comment: Not like that. People are of different kinds. Not five fingers are of equal length. People dominate here to suppress others.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite a well known Stotra so there are plenty of sources for it online but I'm using [this one](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Nava_Graha_Sthothram).

The Stotra dedicates one verse for each of the Grahas. At the end it also has a Phalasruti which mentions the fruits that are obtained upon reciting it.

**Soorya (Sun)**

> Japaa Kusumasankasham Kasyapeyam Maha Dhyuthim 
>   Tamognam
>   Sarvapaapghnam Pranatosmi Divakaram
>
> My salutations to the Sun, Who is like the flower of meditation, Who
>   belongs to the clan of Kashyapa, Who is of greatest brilliance, Who is
>   the destroyer of darkness, And who is the destroyer of all sins.

**Chandra (Moon)**

> Dadhi Shankha tushaa-raabham Khseero Darnava Sambhavam
>   Namaami
>   Shashinam Somam Shambhor Mukuta Bhooshanam
>
> My salutations to the moon, Who is white like the curds and conch, Who
>   was born from the ocean of milk, Who is adorned by a rabbot in him,
>   And who is the ornament of the head of Lord Shiva.

**Mangal or Kuja (Mars)**

> Dharanee garbha sambhootam,Vidyut Kaanti Sama-prabham 
>  Kumaram
>   Shakti Hastam,Tham Mangalaam Pranamamyamaham
>
> Salutations to the mars, Who is born to the earth, Whose shine is
>   equal to lightning, Who is a young man, And who carries the Shakthi.

**Budha (Mercury)**

> Priyangukalika Shyaamam, RoopenaaPratimam Budham 
>  Soumyam Soumya
>   Guno Petham Tam Budham Pranamamyamham
>
> My salutations to Budha, Who is black like the bud of millet, Whose
>   beauty has no equal, Who is gentle by nature, And who is positive.

**Brihaspati or Guru (Jupiter)**

> Deva-naam cha Rishi Naam cha Gurum kaanchana sannibham,
>   Buddhi
>   Bhootam Trilokesham Tam Namaami Brihaspatim
>
> My salutations to Jupiter, Who is teacher of devas and sages, Who is
>   equal in shine to gold, Whose soul is intellect, And who is the lord
>   of all three worlds.

**Shukra (Venus)**

> HimaKundha Mrina-laabham Daitya-naam Paramam Gurum 
>  Sarv aShastra
>   Pravaktaaram Bhargavam Pranamaamyamham
>
> My salutations to Venus, Who shines like the snow white jasmine, Who
>   is the great preceptor of Asuras, Who is an expert in all sciences,
>   And who is the son of the sage Bhrigu.

**Shani (Saturn)**

> Neelanjanasamaabhasam Ravi Putram Yamaagrajam 
>  Chaaya Marthanda
>   Sambhootam Tam Namaami Shanaiswaram
>
> My salutations to God Saturn, Who is the colour of blue- black, Who is
>   the son of Sun God, Who is the elder brother of Yama, And who is the
>   offspring of Sun God and his wife Chaya.

**Rahu**

> Ardha Kaayam Mahaa Veeryam Chandra- Aditya Vimardanam
>   Simhika
>   Garbha Sambhootam Tam Rahum Pranamaamyaham
>
> My salutations to Rahu, Who has only half body, Who is a great hero,
>   Who hurts the Sun and Moon, And who is born out of Simhika.

**Ketu**

> Palaasha Pushpa Sankaasham Tarakaa Graha Mastakam
>   Roudram
>   Roudraa-tmakam Ghoram Tam Ketum Pranamaamya-ham
>
> My salutations TO Kethu, Who has the appearance of a Palashaa flower,
>   Who has a star on his head, Who is terrible to look at, And Who is
>   ugly and the soul of terror.

Then it has the following verse which is a combined prayer to all the nine Grahas.

> Nama Suryaya Somaya Mangalaya Budhaya Cha,
>  Guru Shukra
>   Sanibhyascha, Rahava Kethave Nama.
>
> My salutations to The Sun God, And to the moon, mars, Mercury,
>   Jupiter, Venus, Saturn, Rahu and Kethu.

And after that the author (Vyasa Rishi) mentions his name and the Phalasruti is also given.

> Ithi Vyasa Mukhod Geetham Ya Padeth Susamihitha,
>  Dhiva Vaa, Yadhi
>   Vaa Rathrou Vigna Santhir Bhavishyathi
>  Nara Naari Nrupaanam cha
>   Bhaved, Duswapna naasanam,
>  Iswaryamathulam Teshama arogyam Pushti
>   Vardhanam.
>  Graha Nakshatraja Peeda, taskaragni Samudbhava,
>   Thaa Sarvaa prasamam Yanthi Vyaso Bruthe Na Samsaya.
>
> To any one reading this composed by Vyasa, there would not be any
>   problems in either the day or the night and peace would come to him.
>   Men and women would become kings, their bad dreams would be avoided,
>   They would earn incomparable wealth, and they would lead disease free
>   healthy life. Sage Vyasa tells that they will not suffer dye to the
>   effct of stars or planets, neither by fire or thieves and would lead a
>   very peaceful life.

Comment: What scripture is this found in?

Comment: Possibly not found in any scripture but an independent work of Vyasa @Haridasa

Comment: where can it be found

Comment: Where means what?It can be found in many websites on the net @Haridasa

Comment: the original verses in devangri manuscript.

Comment: @Haridasa https://stotranidhi.com/hi/navagraha-stotram-in-sanskrit/

Comment: I mean like a palm leaf manuscript.

Comment: No idea @Haridasa

Answer (score 1):

श्री नवग्रह स्तोत्र

जपाकुसुम संकाशं काश्यपेयं महदद्युतिम् I 
तमोरिंसर्वपापघ्नं प्रणतोSस्मि दिवाकरम् II १ II >

Japaa kusuma Sankaasam – Kaasyapeyam Mahaath’ yuthim
Thamo’urim sarva Paapa ganam – Pranathosmi Dhiwaakaram>

> One who looks like the Hibiscus flower, Son of Kashyapa, full of radiance,
>   Foe of darkness and the one who dispells all sins, I prostrate that Surya.

दधिशंखतुषाराभं क्षीरोदार्णव संभवम् I 
नमामि शशिनं सोमं शंभोर्मुकुट भूषणम् II २ II

Dhadhi sanka Thushaaraabham – Ksheero Dhaarnava Sambhavam
Namaami sasinam Somam – Sambhor makuta Bhooshanam

> The one who has the hue of curd and icebergs, one who emerges from the milky ocean, Chandra who adorns Shiva, I prostrate. that Chandra.

धरणीगर्भ संभूतं विद्युत्कांति समप्रभम् I 
कुमारं शक्तिहस्तं तं मंगलं प्रणाम्यहम् II ३ II

Dharanee garbha Sambhootham – Vidhyuth kaanthi Samaprabham
Kumaaram Sakthi Hasthancha – Mangalam Pranamaam Yaham

> The one who is the son of Bhooma Devi, One who has the lustre of lightning,
>   One who has Shakti in his hand, and the auspicious one, I prostrate that Angaraka

प्रियंगुकलिकाश्यामं रुपेणाप्रतिमं बुधम् I 
सौम्यं सौम्यगुणोपेतं तं बुधं प्रणमाम्यहम् II ४ II

Piryangu kali Kaasyaamam – Roope’naa Prathimam Budham
Sowmyam sowmya Gunopetham – Tham Bhudham Pranamaam Yaham

> The one who is dark like the bud of Priyangu flower, One who is unequalled in beauty and is intelligent, And the son of Chandra, One who is peaceful, I prostrate that Budha.

देवानांच ऋषीनांच गुरुं कांचन सन्निभम् I 
बुद्धिभूतं त्रिलोकेशं तं नमामि बृहस्पतिम् II ५ II

Dhe’vaanaancha Risheenaancha – Gurum Kaanchan sannibham
Bhudhdhi bhootham Thrilokesam – Thannamaami Bhruhaspathim

> The one who is the Guru of the Devas and Rishis, the one who is radiant and intelligent, The Lord of all the three worlds, I prostrate that Brihaspathi. 
>   हिमकुंद मृणालाभं दैत्यानां परमं गुरुम् I 
>   सर्वशास्त्र प्रवक्तारं भार्गवं प्रणमाम्यहम् II ६ II

Hima kundha M’runaalaabam – Dhaithyaanam Paramam Gurum
Sarva saasthra Pravruththaaram – Bhaargavam Pranamaam Yaham

> The one who has the lustre of the dew, Lotus stem and Thumba flower, High priest of Asuras and the one who preaches the Shatras, I prostrate that ( Bhargava )Sukracharya.

नीलांजन समाभासं रविपुत्रं यमाग्रजम् I 
छायामार्तंड संभूतं तं नमामि शनैश्चरम् II ७ II

Neelaanchana Samaabaasam – Raviputhram Yamaagrajam
Chaayaa Maarthaanda Sambhootham – Thannamaami Sanaicharam

> The one who is blue, one who is like charcoal, one who is the son of Surya and the brother of Yama, one who is born to Chaya and Surya, I prostrate that Saneeswara.

अर्धकायं महावीर्यं चंद्रादित्य विमर्दनम् I 
सिंहिकागर्भसंभूतं तं राहुं प्रणमाम्यहम् II ८ II

Ardha kaayam mahaaveeyram – Chandhraadhithya vimardhanam 
Simhikaagarba Sambhootham – Tham Raahum Pranamaam Yaham

> The one who has half a body and is full of valour, One who opposes Chandra and Surya without fear, One who was born from Simhika’s womb, I prostrate that Rahu.

पलाशपुष्पसंकाशं तारकाग्रह मस्तकम् I 
रौद्रंरौद्रात्मकं घोरं तं केतुं प्रणमाम्यहम् II ९ II

Palaasa pushpa sankaasam – Thaarakagraha masthakam
Rowdhram rowdhraathmakam go’ram – Tham Kethum Pranamaam Yaham.

> The one who looks like Palasa flower, One who is the king of the stars and One who has a fierce form and is scary and angry, I prostrate that Ketu.

इति श्रीव्यासमुखोग्दीतम् यः पठेत् सुसमाहितः I 
दिवा वा यदि वा रात्रौ विघ्न शांतिर्भविष्यति II १० II

Iti Vyaasa-mukhod-giitam yah: path’et-susamaahitah:
Divaa vaa yadi vaa raatrau vighna-shantir-bhavish’yati

> This stotra is composed by Shri Vyaasa Rhishi. A person who chants this stotra during the day or at night will become free from all troubles.

नरनारी नृपाणांच भवेत् दुःस्वप्ननाशनम् I 
ऐश्वर्यमतुलं तेषां आरोग्यं पुष्टिवर्धनम् II ११ II

Nara-naarii-nrupaan’aayn cha bhaved-duh:svapna-naashanam
Aishvaryamatulam tesh’aam aarogyam push’t’i-vardanam 
By chanting this stotra the effect of bad dreams of men, women, kings and so on will be destroyed. Everyone will have good health, wealth and energy.
ग्रहनक्षत्रजाः पीडास्तस्कराग्निसमुभ्दवाः I 
ता सर्वाःप्रशमं यान्ति व्यासोब्रुते न संशयः II १२ II

Graha-nakshatrajaa piid’aah:  taskaraagni-samudbhavaah:
Taah: sarvaah: prashamam yaanti Vyaaso bruute na sanshayah:

A person who chants this stotra becomes free from the troubles created by planets, constellations, thieves, fire etc. Vyasa Rhishi says that there is no doubt about the result of chanting this stotra

II इति श्रीव्यास विरचितम् आदित्यादी नवग्रह स्तोत्रं संपूर्णं II 
Iti Shri Vyaasa-virachitam Navagraha-stotram sampurnam

The Navagraha stotra composed by Shri Vyasa Rishi is Complete here.